# How to restructure the layout to make it better?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

In my app, I have a form where a user enters his/her name and address details. I have created the layout file as shown in the Image. It looks pretty ok but I want it to look better and moreover when the values in the fields city, state, postcode and country get overlapped with each other if the values are long enough.

I have been trying to make the layout better, but now I need some assistance as I do not have much experience in Android programming/ designing. I have attached images to understand better

[image: How it looks without values][image: Explanation of Layouts involved][image: The values being overlapped in city and state]

Here is the XML file for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:id="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar" android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_recipient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp" android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/text_recipient" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Rlayout_recipient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_view" android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/name_hint" android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_name" android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/addr1_hint" android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addr_layout" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/addr2_hint" android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />



    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/addr_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" android:background="@drawable/border_email">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_city"
            android:layout_width="120dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/city_hint" android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_state"
            android:layout_width="125dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edt_rec_city" android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/state_hint" android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_postcode"
            android:layout_width="125dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edt_rec_state" android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/postcode_hint" android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />


        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_ctry"
            android:layout_width="125dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false" android:hint="@string/country_hint"
            android:inputType="text" android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton android:id="@id/btn_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp" android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_save_iphone" />

<ImageButton android:id="@id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_cancel_iphone" />

<Button android:id="@+id/btn_contacts" style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_recipient"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_save"
    android:text="@string/addr_book" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just made some changes which doesn't make the text in each Editext overlap, but I have had to assign fixed width for Editexts in addr_layout. I'm not sure if it's good to do that. Also how can I space the 4 edittexts equally within the relativelayout?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the **RelativeLayout** which id is **android:id="@+id/addr_layout"** with **LinearLayout** and set the orientation of that **LinearLayout** as **horizontal**

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

**Update:**

Replace the following xml portion into your original xml...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/addr_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_email" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/city_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_state"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edt_rec_city"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/state_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_ctry"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edt_rec_state"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="@string/country_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_postcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edt_rec_ctry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="92dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/postcode_hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How do I fit the EditTexts for city, state, pocode, and country to sit beside one another. When I use linearlayout I have to assign fixed width for them. But still country is lying outside and is not visible in the graphical layout of Eclipse

Comment: Forget about the **LinearLayout**. Since you are using **RelativeLayout** then you can use **android:layout_toRightOf** attribute, so that the fields don't overlap each other.

Comment: I made the changes, now they don't overlap with each other. But I have had to assign a fixed width to each one of them. I'm not sure if it is good and will be consistent on various devices. Also how to space the 4 editexts equally?

Comment: In **LinearLayout**, it is easier to space the 4 editexts equally. So first of all, I have to know in which way you solve the previous problem.

Comment: I have made the changes as you said..See the edited code

Comment: From your update what I understand is that your are nor clear what I'm saying...so please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bar">

            <ImageButton android:id="@id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_cancel_iphone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_recipient"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/text_recipient"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button android:id="@+id/btn_contacts"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/addr_book" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton android:id="@id/btn_save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_save_iphone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_email"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/name_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_email"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/addr1_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_email"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/addr2_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_city"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/city_hint" android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_state"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/state_hint"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />


            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_ctry"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/country_hint"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_postcode"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/postcode_hint"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Isn't using many linearlayouts more expensive than RelativeLayout? Also why is ScrollView required?

Comment: Nop!!! LinearLayout easly handle your requirement and i put as ScrollView as parent becz if any smaller device your layout working as properly ....

Answer (score 1):

instead of `lower Relative Layout` u can use `Linear Layout(Horizontal)` with `android:weight` attribute for each `EditText` if u give same weight for each child those child will occupy same space from parent layout

code sample

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/addr_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"                 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/border_email">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_city"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weight="1"
            android:ems="10" 
            android:hint="@string/city_hint" 
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_state"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/state_hint" 
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_postcode"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weight="1" 
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/postcode_hint" 
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="6dp" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />


        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_ctry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:weight="1" 
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:hint="@string/country_hint"
            android:inputType="text" 
            android:padding="6dp" 
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />


</LinearLayout>
```